# FME Workspace Update rows WHERE

Tags: file-geodatabase, update, fme-form

[image]

This is about the lower part of `TesterNoType`

In table 1 I have ex

```
Filename, Type, Date
Parks,    1,    2018-01-22
Parks,    4,    2018-01-22
```

Table 2 aka `new information table` I have information about 1000 parks
In table 3 aka `old information table` I have 988 parks, some have stayed the same and should not be changed, some have old info about the type of the park

I have another workspace where I send the filename as `Feature to Read` and reads the table and writes to table 2.

In the old one with no types I only wrote the reader from the new and truncated the old and voila, but here I can't truncate, I want to both add all new rows and for every row that has type 1 for example (same obj id can happen in old and new or not).

I only want to replace every single row in table 3 that has type 1 and replace it with the information from table 2 instead. All that not has type 1 should still be there.

I'm doing a very simplified version of this now where I only read `Parks, 1`
and should read parks table from the old GDB and write to another GDB where I have the old version of Parks, but the writing part where I only want to replace where attribute `type=1` doesn't seem to be working.

Should I do a SQL script somewhere or only read rows where `type=1` or find another way to do this?

[image]

Comment: What is the FME version you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update an existing GDB several options are:

- Set "Writer Mode" to "Update" (Navigator, Writer, Parameters, Advanced, Writer Mode) and use Update/Delete Key Fields.
- Assign the attribute "fme_db_operation" with value "UPDATE" to each feature.
- Run SQL after write. (Navigator, Writer, Parameters, Advanced, SQL To Run After Write)

The Update/Delete Key Fields are used to identify the rows in the target dataset. For file geodatabases this could be OBJECTID. (this generates the script UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2 WHERE OBJECTID = 1)